# Thank you for explaining vs Thank you for the explanation

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the 2 expressions and which one is more commonly used?

Please show me example usage of the 2 expressions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that there's a significant difference in meaning. The second version sounds a bit more formal, so the first might be a bit more common...but I doubt by much.